# Insert return after every other image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to know if it's possible to add two Chr(11) returns after every *other* image. At the moment I have this code, which resizes them all and adds two returns. However, I can fit two images on a line and as such I need the returns after every other photo (2 photos per line, with two Chr(11) between each line).

Hopefully this is clear. Here is the code I have so far

```
Sub resize()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
.ScaleHeight = 14
.ScaleWidth = 14
.Range.InsertAfter Chr(11)
.Range.InsertAfter Chr(11)
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Put the insert-command in an `If`-statement: `If i mod 2 = 0 Then`

Comment: @FunThomas sorry could you clarify where I need to insert that? Beginner here!

Comment: You want the Chr(11) only to appear after 2 images, right? That means `i` must be even. Just put the If-statement *before* the lines that add the Chr(11) and the `End If` *after* those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check out: https://www.msofficeforums.com/47919-post2.html.

In any event, what you're describing for the line breaks can be done with a simple Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = ^g^g
Replace = ^&^l^l
```

Hence:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iSHp As InlineShape
With ActiveDocument
  For Each iSHp In .InlineShapes
    iSHp.ScaleHeight = 14
    iSHp.ScaleWidth = 14
  Next
  With .Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Text = "^g^g"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&^l^l"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 to .InlineShapes.Count
    With .InlineShapes(i)
      .ScaleHeight = 14
      .ScaleWidth = 14
      If i Mod 2 = 0 then .Range.InsertAfter Chr(11) & Chr(11)
    End with
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```